# Is there a way to reuse the same Azure Storage Plan and Azure App Service Plan to host multiple Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created 1 node.js and 1 java Azure Function, using VS Code

When I have deployed just these 2 functions to Azure using VS Code, I ended up with this many Azure resources (see the picture below).

Is there a way to re-use the same resource type (i.e. App Service, Storage Account, etc..) to host multiple Azure Functions?

[image: Azure Resources]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, we do this all the time. We usually create resources in the portal by hand the first time and later use deployment scripts (msdeploy or Powershell) to update the resources.

When you create a new Function App in the portal, you can tell Azure to put the new Function App in an existing App Service Plan and also set it to use existing storage:

[image]

You can also do this using Azure CLI if you are a CLI guy.

Comment: Found this page with the exact syntax, which brings together the service plan, storage account and a function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-create-app-service-plan